# Frameset not working in android 4.0 webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-browser

I want to use two html in a single webpage so i choose to implement frameset in html. it works fine in all android version except android4.0. If i html file in default browser its working fine but in webview only one frame is loaded not the other ie first frame is override by second frame so it looks only second frame is loading.

here is my code for loading html in webview..

```
 WebView web=new WebView(this);
 String url="<html><frameset cols=\"25%,25%\" FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=0><frame src=\"file:///android_asset/preview.html"
          +"\" /><frame src=\"file:///android_asset/preview.html\" /> </frameset></html>";

web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:/"+baseurl+"/",url, "text/html", "utf-8","");
```

i dont know why its not supporting in android4.0 whether android webview is not accepting  frame in 4.0 or not? If anyone knows please help me..

Comment: I have faced this issue? Could you find a solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256857/android-webview-find-element-doesnt-work-before-kitkat-version