# android webview find element doesn't work before Kitkat version

Tags: javascript, android, webview, getelementbyid

I have a app which clicks automatically button by javascript. It works fine but before Kitkat versions `find element doesn't work`.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.frames['top_level'].document.getElementById('enter_desktop').click();");
    }
});
```

Before Kitkat `window.frames['top_level'].document.getElementById('enter_desktop')` returns frame's src value not my element.Please help me? Thanks in advance!